# How can I create Kafka stream from Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, memgraphdb

How can I create a Kafka stream directly from Python? I know that I need to use GQLAlchemy but I don't know the exact commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy) is a fully open-source Python library and Object Graph Mapper (OGM) - a link between graph database objects and Python objects.

An Object Graph Mapper or OGM provides a developer-friendly workflow that allows for writing object-oriented notation to communicate with graph databases. This means that instead of writing Cypher queries, you can write object-oriented code, which the OGM will automatically translate into Cypher queries.

You can use the following code to connect to the Kafka stream:

```
from gqlalchemy import MemgraphKafkaStream

stream = MemgraphKafkaStream(name="ratings_stream", topics=["ratings"], transform="movielens.rating", bootstrap_servers="localhost:9093")
db.create_stream(stream)
db.start_stream(stream)
```